# Как сделать селектор без индекса

Tags: jquery

Есть группа селекторов

```
...
#article-node-form--3 #edit-body--3 
#article-node-form--4 #edit-body--4 
...
```

как к ним обратиться без индексов?

Я пробовал так - у  меня  не  получилось:

```
$('div[id^="article-node-form"] div[id^="edit-body"]')
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div id="article-node-form--3"><div id="edit-body--3">123</div></div>
<div id="article-node-form--4"><div id="edit-body--4">456</div></div>
```

js:

```
jQuery('div[id^=article-node-form] div[id^=edit-body]').css({
color: 'red'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sod2efpz/